# Stata - Creating a set of all possible unmatched pairs

Tags: stata

I have observational data of observed matched pairs (supplier-buyer) which I would like to use to build a set of counterfactual observations.
Suppose we observe two suppliers (X and Y) and 3 buyers (A, B, and C).
We observe that supplier X has a $2M contract with buyer A, and a $5M contract with buyer B.
We also observe that supplier Y has only one contract with buyer C worth $4M. 
I would like to build a set of counterfactuals based on the set of unmatched pairs. I want to place a hypothetical contract value for each counterfactual observation that is equal to the maximum of what each party contracted at in the observed data. For example, this is what we would get for the counterfactuals based on the observations above:

Counterfactual observation #1: X with C for a value of $5M (because X has $5M for his observed largest contract and C has $4M, $5M is higher)
Counterfactual observation #2: Y with A for a value of $4M (because Y has $4M for his observed largest contract and A has $2M, $4M is higher)
Counterfactual observation #3: Y with B for a value of $5M (because Y has $4M for his observed largest contract and B has $5M, $5M is higher)

and here's the Stata sample code depicting my data..

```
clear
input str3(supplier buyer) float cont_value
"X" "A" 2
"X" "B" 5
"Y" "C" 4
end
```

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1314226-building-a-set-of-counterfactuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear
set more off

input str3(supplier buyer) value
"X" "A" 2
"X" "B" 5
"Y" "C" 4
end

list

fillin supplier buyer

list, sepby(supplier)

bysort supplier : egen maxsupp = max(value) 
bysort buyer : egen maxbuy = max(value)

egen value2 = rowmax(max*) if _fillin
replace value2 = value if !_fillin

sort supplier buyer
order value2, after(value)
list, sepby(supplier)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer on Statalist which `merge`s a series of datasets, you can achieve this with `fillin`.

```
clear *
input str3(supplier buyer) float cont_value
"X" "A" 2
"X" "B" 5
"Y" "C" 4
end

fillin supplier buyer
list 

tempvar cont_val cont_val1
by supplier, sort : egen `cont_val' = max(cont_value) 
by buyer, sort : egen `cont_val1' = max(cont_value)

egen cont_val = rowmax(`cont_val' `cont_val1') if _fillin
replace cont_val = cont_value if !_fillin

drop _fillin
sort supplier buyer

list supplier buyer cont_value cont_val
```

Comment: Your answer went through before mine, which is virtually the same. The only suggestion I have here is to condition on `_fillin` and not on `cont_value`, when creating the final result.

Comment: Yes, I see the logic there. Although I just wonder if OP would mean to create these counterfactuals for only supplier-buyer pairs which don't exist or for any missing value of `cont_value` (reading the question again, OP doesn't mention this so perhaps `_fillin` is correct).  Of course if `cont_value` is non-missing for all existing supplier-buyer then the result is the same. Overall, I think I agree with your suggestion. Thanks.